# Error on uploading image in django: "coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found"

Tags: django, image-uploading, modelform, imagefield

Trying to work with **ImageField** in django.
Here are my **models**

```
class Album(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Photo(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/')
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="")

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class PhotoModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Photo
```

Here is a part of **urls.py**

```
...
url(r'^trial/upload/$', 'trial.views.upload'),
...
```

**views.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PhotoModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            photo = form.save()
            return render_to_response('trial/thanks_upload.html',{
                'photo': photo
            }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = PhotoModelForm()
    return render_to_response('trial/upload.html', {
      'form': form
    }, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**upload.html**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/trial/upload/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="fieldWrapper">
            {{ field.errors }}
            {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>
</form>
```

But on saving I have next error:
**TypeError at /trial/upload/
coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found**

Errors appears on **photo.save**

Does anybody has ideas why could it be? Why **tuple** appears at all? I'm sure there is a stupid bug...

Comment: Can you tell the line where the error occurs?

Comment: in **views.py** where **photo = form.save()** goes

Comment: Looks like you typed extra comma somewhere.

Comment: Where could it be? I've listed the source code above.

Comment: @DrTyrsa, you were right! It was in my setting.py file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've got it myself. In settings.py there is MEDIA_ROOT setting, which was

```
MEDIA_ROOT = 'd:/dev/python/scripts/app/media/',
```

Python makes the object tuple because of the comma at the end. That's why it couldn't save the object. Watch your commas next time!

Comment: It's amazing how sb else had the same problem and publish it on internet